# Values after join are incorrect

Tags: sql

I have 2 database tables. Table A has to fetch some records based on parameter passed there may or may not be an entry in table B with that key.

What I want to do is:

```
select a.col1,a.col2,a.col3
FROM   table   WHERE  a.id = 123
```

This would fetch 20 rows. For one of the rows there is an entry in another table B.

```
select T_level from table b where b.id = 123
```

only one record appears with right value.

What I want is to get this in a single query. Something like:

```
select a.col1,a.col2,a.col3,b.T_level 
from a,b 
where a.id = 123
and a.id = b.id
```

When I do that, I get 20 rows and the column T_level as '50' for all the rows, whereas it should be '50' for one correct row, for rest it should be null.

I further tried:

```
select a.col1,a.col2,a.col3,nvl(b.T_level,0) from a,b
```

but that doesn't fetch the way I expect.

Comment: The question is unclear (to me). A few rows of sample data could help us a lot to understand the case.

Comment: also tag your DBMS and provide sample data and expect output, this question in current state is unclear and difficult to answer.

Comment: col1 col2  col3  id
1   Y  Z  123
2   bb CC 123
3   gg tt  123
4     rr    dd  123
table b
Id  col1 T_level
123      1  50
123      2  20

information  would like to get -

col1 col2  col3  id  T_level 
1   Y  Z  123  50
2   bb CC 123  20
3   gg tt  123  NULL
4     rr    dd  123  NULL

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, please learn to use ansi sql join syntax. The Oracle join syntax you are using hasn't been considered good practice for decades

[SQL Join syntax](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL))

If you want to get all records from a and any matching records from b then you need to use a LEFT OUTER JOIN